# Two different function prototypes for Linux kernel module ioctl

Tags: linux-kernel, drivers, kernel-modules, function, ioctl

As pointed out in [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441321/48707), the prototype for the `ioctl` function inside a Linux kernel module is:

(version 1)

```
int ioctl(struct inode *i, struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);
```

or

(version 2)

```
long ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);
```

I would like to use them in a kernel module which implements a character device driver.

1. Are both the above prototypes suitable in this case? If yes, why? If no, how to choose the right one?
2. What header/source file(s) contain these prototypes? In other words: what is the official reference file for these prototypes?

I'm running Ubuntu 20.04 on `x86_64` and these are my available header files:

```
/usr/include/asm-generic/ioctl.h
/usr/include/linux/ioctl.h
/usr/include/linux/mmc/ioctl.h
/usr/include/linux/hdlc/ioctl.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ioctl.h
/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/asm/ioctl.h
```

The only significant line is in `/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/sys/ioctl.h`:

```
extern int ioctl (int __fd, unsigned long int __request, ...) __THROW;
```

but I can't find here any clue about the above two alternative prototypes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Are both the above prototypes suitable in this case? If yes, why? If no, how to choose the right one?

They are not both suitable. Only *version 2* is currently available in the kernel, so this is the version that should be used.

> 2. What header/source file(s) contain these prototypes? In other words: what is the official reference file for these prototypes?

They are in `include/linux/fs.h` (this is a path relative to the kernel sourcecode root directory), inside the `struct file_operations` definition:

```
long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

That is: the member `unlocked_ioctl` must be a pointer to a function

```
long ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg);
```

which is exactly *version 2*. If a function `my_ioctl()` is defined inside a kernel module using *version 1* instead, a compiler error will be generated:

```
error: initialization of ‘long int (*)(struct file *, unsigned int,  long unsigned int)’ from incompatible pointer type ‘long int (*)(struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int,  long unsigned int)’ [-Werror=incompatible-pointer-types]
  .unlocked_ioctl = my_ioctl
                    ^~~~~~~~
```

---

**Some additional comments**

*Version 1* has been the only one, till [kernel 2.6.10](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.10/source/include/linux/fs.h#L917), where `struct file_operations` only had

```
int (*ioctl) (struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

This `ioctl` function, however, created a Big Kernel Lock (BKL): it locked the whole kernel during its operation. This is undesirable. So, from [2.6.11](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.11/source/include/linux/fs.h#L931),

```
int (*ioctl) (struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
long (*unlocked_ioctl) (struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

A new way to use `ioctl`s has been introduced, which did not lock the kernel. Here the old `ioctl` with kernel lock and the new `unlocked_ioctl` coexist. From [2.6.36](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v2.6.36/source/include/linux/fs.h#L1497), the old `ioctl` has been removed. All the drivers should be updated accordingly, to only use `unlocked_ioctl`. Refer to [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/4733/48707) for more information.

In a recent kernel release (5.15.2), it seems that there are still few files using the old `ioctl`:

```
linux-5.15.2$ grep -r "ioctl(struct inode" *
Documentation/cdrom/cdrom-standard.rst: int cdrom_ioctl(struct inode *ip, struct file *fp,
drivers/staging/vme/devices/vme_user.c:static int vme_user_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *file,
drivers/scsi/dpti.h:static int adpt_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *file, uint cmd, ulong arg);
drivers/scsi/dpt_i2o.c:static int adpt_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct file *file, uint cmd, ulong arg)
fs/fuse/ioctl.c:static int fuse_priv_ioctl(struct inode *inode, struct fuse_file *ff,
fs/btrfs/ioctl.c:static noinline int search_ioctl(struct inode *inode,
fs/ocfs2/refcounttree.h:int ocfs2_reflink_ioctl(struct inode *inode,
fs/ocfs2/refcounttree.c:int ocfs2_reflink_ioctl(struct inode *inode,
net/sunrpc/cache.c:static int cache_ioctl(struct inode *ino, struct file *filp,
```

`vme_user.c`, `dpt_i2o.c` and `cache.c`, however, have:

```
static const struct file_operations adpt_fops = {
        .unlocked_ioctl = adpt_unlocked_ioctl,
```

and then

```
static long adpt_unlocked_ioctl(struct file *file, uint cmd, ulong arg)
{
        struct inode *inode;
        long ret;

        inode = file_inode(file);

        mutex_lock(&adpt_mutex);
        ret = adpt_ioctl(inode, file, cmd, arg);
```

So they use the old version, inside the new (getting the `inode` from the available data, as suggested by Andy Dalton in the comments). As regards the files inside `fs`: they seem not to use a `struct file_operations`; also, their functions are not the `ioctl` defined in

```
int (*ioctl) (struct inode *, struct file *, unsigned int, unsigned long);
```

because they take different parameters (`fuse_priv_ioctl` in `fs/fuse/ioctl.c`, `search_ioctl` in `fs/btrfs/ioctl.c`, `ocfs2_reflink_ioctl` in `fs/ocfs2/refcounttree.c`), so they maybe are only used internally in the driver.

So, the assumption in the [linked question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441321/48707) that two versions are available for the `ioctl` function inside a Linux kernel module is wrong. Only `unlocked_ioctl` (*version 2*) must be used.

Answer (score 2):

You're looking at functions that are defined in different contexts.  The third one:

```c
extern int ioctl (int __fd, unsigned long int __request, ...) __THROW;
```

is a *system call*  (i.e., a call from userspace to kernelspace).

The others look like functions defined in the kernel (both `struct file` and `struct inode` are kernel data structures).

A call to the system call from some userspace program will

```
   +-------------------+
   | userspace program |
   +-------------------+
            |
ioctl(fd, requestType, arg);
            |
            |                                           userspace
-------------------------------------------------------------------
            |                                           kernelspace
            v
SYSCALL_DEFINE3(ioctl...) /* ${kernel_root}/fs/ioctl.c */
            |
            v
      do_vfs_ioctl(...)
            |
 /*
   look at fd, map it to the device driver.  Call the ioctl
   registered for that device type.

   for example: drivers/char/random.c:

   const struct file_operations random_fops = {
        ...
        .unlocked_ioctl = random_ioctl,
        ...
   };
            |
            V
static long random_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
```

Why are some `struct file` and others `struct inode`?  I don't know for sure, but I imagine that it probably depend on the type of device associated with the given file descriptor (the `fd` parameter to the system call).  The VFS layer might dispatch to different types of registered drivers.  For example, device drivers might use `struct file` while filesystem drivers might use `struct inode`.

**Edit**

If your question is *How do I write a *character* device driver that supports the `ioctl` system call?*, then here is a simple example:

```c
#include <linux/fs.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#include <linux/module.h>

static int example_device_major_number;
static const char example_device_name[] = "example-driver";

#define LOG(fmt, ...) printk(KERN_NOTICE "%s[%s:%d]: " fmt "\n", example_device_name, __FUNCTION__, __LINE__, ##__VA_ARGS__)

static long example_module_ioctl(struct file *, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)
{
    LOG("cmd: %d, arg: %lu", cmd, arg);
    return 0;
}

static struct file_operations example_module_fops =
{
    .owner          = THIS_MODULE,
    .unlocked_ioctl = example_module_ioctl,
};

static int example_module_init(void)
{
    int result = 0;

    result = register_chrdev(0, example_device_name, &example_module_fops);
    if (result < 0)
    {
            LOG("Can't register character device with error code = %d", result);
            return result;
    }

    example_device_major_number = result;

    LOG("Registered character device with major number = %d", example_device_major_number);

    return 0;
}

static void example_module_exit(void)
{
    if (example_device_major_number != 0)
    {
        unregister_chrdev(example_device_major_number, example_device_name);
    }
    LOG("Module removed");
}

module_init(example_module_init);
module_exit(example_module_exit);
MODULE_LICENSE("GPL");
```

If I compile and load that module, I see this in the output of `dmesg`:

```
[1325403.600381] example-driver[example_module_init:35]: Registered character device with major number = 238
```

From that, I see that the kernel has assigned major number 238 to my newly-added character device driver.

Now, I can create a character device file with that major number:

```
$ sudo mknod mydevice c 238 0
$ ls -l mydevice
crw-r--r-- 1 root root 238, 0 Nov 26 17:03 mydevice
```

Next, I can write a userspace program to (1) open that device file, and (2) call `ioctl()` on the resulting file descriptor:

```c
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    int fd = open("mydevice", O_RDWR);
    if (fd < 0) {
        perror("open");
        return 1;
    }

    int rc = ioctl(fd, 1, 2);
    if (rc < 0) {
        perror("ioctl");
    }

    (void) close(fd);

    return 0;
}
```

With the module previously loaded, if I compile and run the userspace application, I see the following in output of `dmesg`

```
[1325593.158303] example-driver[example_module_ioctl:12]: cmd: 1, arg: 2
```

Comment: This explains even better your answer to the [mentioned question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441321/48707). Thank you. I edited my question to further clarify my problem. My doubt was mainly about the two different versions for `random_ioctl`. How to choose the right one? And where are they specified in the sourcecode? Also, I don't think it is `struct inode` vs `struct file`, because when passing `struct inode` as a parameter (required in version 1), also a `struct file` must be passed.

Comment: Please, check out my edited question. Version 1 is the one with a `struct inode` as first parameter, version 2 is the one with `struct file` as first parameter.

Comment: Yes, but `random_ioctl()` doesn't have two versions, it is only `static long random_ioctl(struct file *f, unsigned int cmd, unsigned long arg)`.  Like I said in my answer, my guess is that some types of drivers work on `struct file` while other types of driver work on `struct inode`.  Grepping the source tree, I see ioctl functions with `struct inode` mainly in filesystem drivers.

Comment: Then, correct me if I'm wrong. I must define `some_ioctl()` inside a kernel module which represents a character device file. `some_ioctl()` is like `random_ioctl`, but for my module. If, inside `some_ioctl()`, I need to use the `struct inode`, I will use version 1; instead, if I just need the file descriptor, I will use version 2. In other words: both versions are allowed, but I choose one of them according to my needs *inside* `some_ioctl()`. Is it right?

Comment: I think if you're writing a character device driver, then you'll provide an `ioctl` that takes a `file*`.  If your implementation needs an `inode*` for something, you'll have to write code that to find that object with what you're given.  Note, for example, that `struct file` has a `struct inode*`: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/latest/source/include/linux/fs.h#L965

Comment: @BowPark I updated the answer with a sample if that's helpful.

Comment: Thank you so much. It is useful, but it does not answer my two specific questions. I wrote an answer.